# AWS CLI Cognito User Pool Client Creation fails

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-cli

I've got a Cognito user pool in AWS, and I'm trying to create a Bash script to add an app client to it using [`aws cli`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-idp/create-user-pool-client.html).

I'm running the following:

```
aws cognito-idp create-user-pool-client \
 --user-pool-id $user_pool_id \
 --client-name toy-client \
 --callback-urls "https://example.com"
```

where `user_pool_id` is set to the id of my user pool.

When I do so, I get a long error, of which this is the first few characters:

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the CreateUserPoolClient operation: 2 validation errors detected: Value '[<, !, d, o, c, t, y, p, e,  , h, t, m, l, >, 
, <, h, t, m, l, >, 
, <, h, e, a, d, >, 
,  ,  ,  ,  , <, t, i, t, l, e, >, E, x, a, m, p, l, e,  , D, o, m, a, i, n, <, /, t, i, t, l, e, >...
```

It looks very much like it's retrieved `https://example.com`, which it does to verify it's accessible, but then it seems to be using the contents in place of the URL.

If I set this URL as the `callback_url` when creating an app client in the AWS console, it works fine.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, or is this a bug?

Comment: That aws-cli v1.x asks for a callback url, then proceeds to crawl it, is absurd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the CLI isn't configured to accept the callback URL as a string and is instead [loading the URL and passing the response as the parameter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-parameters-file.html#cli-usage-parameters-file-remote).

Ensure you are running the latest version of the CLI (preferably version 2). If you can't use v2 for whatever reason you can fix this behavior by setting `cli_follow_urlparam = false` in your aws config file `~/.aws/config` as specified [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkref/latest/guide/setting-global-cli_follow_urlparam.html).